# R Strptime Year and Month with No Delimiter returning NA

Tags: r, time

I'm probably doing something stupid and not seeing it, but:

```
> strptime("201101","%Y%m")
[1] NA
```

From help strptime:

> %Y Year with century
>   %m Month as decimal number (01–12)

Comment: You found the documentation bug with *`strptime`* that year-month-day must all be supplied, which is never stated anywhere: *"For strptime the input string need not specify the date completely: it is assumed that unspecified seconds, minutes or hours are zero, and an unspecified year, month or day is the current one."*

Comment: thanks for this comment. Even more strange: when doing that only with "%Y" (on my computer) it automatically add "12-27" for month and day and return a valide value. But when trying "%Y-%m" it return `NA`. this started to drive me crazy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just paste a day field (say, "01") that you ignore:

```
R> shortdate <- "201101"
R> as.Date(paste(shortdate, "01", sep=""), "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2011-01-01"
R>
```

I prefer `as.Date()` for dates and `strptime()` for `POSIXct` objects, i.e. dates and times.

You can then convert the parsed `Date` object into a `POSIXlt` object to retrieve year and month:

```
R> mydt <- as.Date(paste(shortdate, "01", sep=""), "%Y%m%d")
R> myp <- as.POSIXlt(mydt)
R> c(myp$year, myp$mon)
[1] 111   0
R>
```

This is standard POSIX behaviour with years as "year - 1900" and months as zero-indexed.

*Edit seven years later:* For completeness, and as someone just upvoted this, the functions in my [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package can help:

```
R> anytime::anydate("201101")    ## returns a Date
[1] "2011-01-01"
R> anytime::anytime("201101")    ## returns a Datetime
[1] "2011-01-01 CST"
R>
```

The use a different parser (from [Boost Date_time](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/date_time.html) which is more generous and imputes the missing day (or day/hour/minute/second in the second case).

Comment: so in R you can not say that there is no day digit, you have to inject the assumption of 01. strange.

Comment: isn't this an R bug though? because `strptime("11", "%m")` returns `NA`, while `strptime("11", "%d")` and `strptime("11", "%y")` return sensible results. As if R has got an issue with `%m` specifcally.