# POSIX date from dates in weekly time format

Tags: r, date, posix

I have dates encoded in a weekly time format (European convention >> `01` through `52`/`53`, e.g. `"2016-48"`) and would like to standardize them to a POSIX date:

```
require(magrittr)
(x <- as.POSIXct("2016-12-01") %>% format("%Y-%V"))
# [1] "2016-48"
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%V")
# [1] "2016-01-11 CET"
```

I expected the last statement to return `"2016-12-01"` again. What am I missing here?

---

## Edit

Thanks to Dirk, I was able to piece it together:

```
y <- sprintf("%s-1", x)
```

While I still don't get why this doesn't work

```
(as.POSIXct(y, format = "%Y-%V-%u"))
# [1] "2016-01-11 CET"
```

this does

```
(as.POSIXct(y, format = "%Y-%U-%u")
# [1] "2016-11-28 CET"
```

## Edit 2

Oh my, I think using `%V` is a **very** bad idea in general:

```
as.POSIXct("2016-01-01") %>% format("%Y-%V")
# [1] "2016-53"
```

**Should this be considered to be on a "serious bug" level that requires further action?!**

Sticking to either `%U` or `%W` seems to be the right way to go

```
as.POSIXct("2016-01-01") %>% format("%Y-%U")
# [1] "2016-00"
```

## Edit 3

Nope, not quite finished/still puzzled: the approach doesn't work for the very first week

```
(x <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01") %>% format("%Y-%W"))
# [1] "2016-00"

as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s-1", x), format = "%Y-%W-%u")
# [1] NA
```

It does for week `01` as defined in the underlying convention when using `%U` or `%W` (so "week 2", actually)

```
as.POSIXct("2016-01-1", format = "%Y-%W-%u")
# [1] "2016-01-04 CET"
```

Comment: You can _reduce_ a date to a year-week number, but you cannot go back as there are seven possibly values in that week.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: aha, that makes sense. Do you know of any workarounds? I do need to infer the month, I don't really care about the exact day

Comment: From memory there is also a _weekday_ formatter.  If you just append a value (one, say) you should have the beginning of the week.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks Dirk! R doesn't really seem to like `%V` though - even though it says it does, sort of, in `strptime` ;-) As always: what a pain. In that regard: thanks for `anydate`!

Comment: Related: [How to Parse Year + Week Number in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380435/how-to-parse-year-week-number-in-r)

Comment: @Henrik thanks for the pointer

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel could you think of any fix for making the hack work for the *very first* week (`00` in `%U` or `%W` convention)? See **Edit 3** for an example

Comment: Unsure. My instinct would be to examine how C library variant of `strptime()` / `strftime()` works on your OS.  I think on all-but-Windows R uses the external C library one.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks... stupid Windows ;-) I don't know anything about C, but maybe I'll manage to find it somehow. At all: any help in shedding light on this greatly appreciated

Comment: I had issues with `%V` here too when testing, and I am on Ubuntu.  There may be something else going on but I don't have the spare time to go digging.  Most importantly we have your question answered.

Comment: As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45543682/3817004) in more detail, you need to use the  `%G` week-based year format specifier instead of `%Y` when formating dates as ISO week, i.e., `%G-W%V-%u` for one of the ISO 8601 compliant formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have to deal a lot with reporting by ISO weeks, I've created the [`ISOweek` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ISOweek/index.html) some years ago.

The package includes the function  `ISOweek2date()` which *returns the date of a given weekdate (year, week of the year, day of week according to ISO 8601). It's the inverse function to `date2ISOweek()`.*

With `ISOweek`, your examples become:

```
library(ISOweek)

# define dates to convert
dates <- as.Date(c("2016-12-01", "2016-01-01"))

# convert to full ISO 8601 week-based date yyyy-Www-d
(week_dates <- date2ISOweek(dates))
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-W48-4" "2015-W53-5"
> ```

```
# convert back to class Date 
ISOweek2date(week_dates)
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-12-01" "2016-01-01"
> ```

Note that `date2ISOweek()` requires a full  [ISO week-based date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) in the format `yyyy-Www-d` including the day of the week (1 to 7, Monday to Sunday).

So, if you only have year and ISO week number you have to create a character string with a day of the week specified.

A typical phrase in many reports is, e.g., "*reporting week 31 ending 2017-08-06*":h

```
yr <- 2017
wk <- 31
ISOweek2date(sprintf("%4i-W%02i-%1i", yr, wk, 7))
```

> ```
>  [1] "2017-08-06"
> ```

#### Addendum

Please, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41726589/3817004) for another use case and more background information on the `ISOweek` package.