# as.Date produces unexpected result in a sequence of week-based dates

Tags: r, date, as.date

I am working on the transformation of week based dates to month based dates.

When checking my work, I found the following problem in my data which is the result of a simple call to `as.Date()`

```
as.Date("2016-50-4", format = "%Y-%U-%u")
as.Date("2016-50-5", format = "%Y-%U-%u")
as.Date("2016-50-6", format = "%Y-%U-%u")
as.Date("2016-50-7", format = "%Y-%U-%u") # this is the problem
```

The previous code yields correct date for the first 3 lines:

```
"2016-12-15"
"2016-12-16"
"2016-12-17"
```

The last line of code  however, goes back 1 week:

```
 "2016-12-11"
```

Can anybody explain what is happening here?

Comment: The issue is that %u starts with Monday, and %U starts with Sunday, so `as.Date("2016-50-7", format = "%Y-%U-%u")` is interpreted as the first day (Sunday) of week 50. See `?strptime` to verify.

Comment: following @Imo's comment, `as.Date("2016-50-7", format = "%Y-%V-%u")` seems to work, but would produce different results than your example for some years - how important this is may depend on your application

Comment: @Miff on my computer that results in `"2016-01-18"` which isn't the correct date

Comment: @Miff on my computer I get the same result Jaap mentions "2016-01-18",  for all lines of input i.e.: "2016-50-4" and so on

Comment: @lmo, I'd say that `as.Date("2016-50-7", format = "%Y-%U-%u")` is interpreted as the **seventh** day (Sunday) of week 50

Comment: @DarshanBaral Take a closer look at the OP's output, or copy and paste each line of code and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working with week of the year can become very tricky. You may try to convert the dates using the `ISOweek` package:

```
# create date strings in the format given by the OP
wd <- c("2016-50-4","2016-50-5","2016-50-6","2016-50-7", "2016-51-1", "2016-52-7")
# convert to "normal" dates
ISOweek::ISOweek2date(stringr::str_replace(wd, "-", "-W"))
```

The result

```
#[1] "2016-12-15" "2016-12-16" "2016-12-17" "2016-12-18" "2016-12-19" "2017-01-01"
```

is of class `Date`.

Note that the ISO week-based date format is `yyyy-Www-d` with a capital `W` preceeding the week number. This is required to distinguish it from the standard month-based date format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

So, in order to convert the date strings provided by the OP using `ISOweek2date()` it is necessary to insert a `W` after the first hyphen which is accomplished by replacing the first `-` by `-W` in each string.

Also note that ISO weeks start on Monday and the days of the week are numbered 1 to 7. The year which belongs to an ISO week may differ from the calendar year. This can be seen from the sample dates above where the week-based date `2016-W52-7` is converted to `2017-01-01`.

### About the `ISOweek` package

Back in 2011, the `%G`, `%g`, `%u`, and `%V` format specifications weren't available to `strptime()` in the Windows version of R. This was annoying as I had to prepare weekly reports including week-on-week comparisons. I spent hours to find a solution for dealing with ISO weeks, ISO weekdays, and ISO years. Finally, I ended up creating the `ISOweek` package and publishing it [on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ISOweek/index.html). Today, the package still has its merits as the aforementioned formats are ignored on input (see `?strptime` for details).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution and time. I will work with Darshan Barans elaboration on your post.

Comment: I did some manual testing on your proposal: i.e. one line of code using the ISOweek package. So far, this seems to work perfectly. I will now run this is my full dataset and report back.

Comment: In all its simplicity, this continues to work without problems for my dataset with dates from 2014-2017(now). A big thank you !

Comment: I have tested Uwe Block's solution on a dataset with dates from 2004 up to halfway January 2017. This approach works perfectly.

Comment: @KoenV Glad to hear that and thank for all the testing.

Answer (score 5):

As @lmo said in the comments, `%u` stands for the weekdays as a decimal number (1–7, with Monday as 1) and `%U` stands for the week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Sunday as the first day. Thus, `as.Date("2016-50-7", format = "%Y-%U-%u")` will result in `"2016-12-11"`.

However, if that should give `"2016-12-18"`, then you should use a week format that has also Monday as starting day. According to the documentation of `?strptime` you would expect that the format `"%Y-%V-%u"` thus gives the correct output, where `%V` stands for the week of the year as decimal number (01–53) with monday as the first day.

Unfortunately, it doesn't:

```
> as.Date("2016-50-7", format = "%Y-%V-%u")
[1] "2016-01-18"
```

However, at the end of the explanation of `%V` it sais *"Accepted but ignored on input"* meaning that it won't work.

You can circumvent this behavior as follows to get the correct dates:

```
# create a vector of dates
d <- c("2016-50-4","2016-50-5","2016-50-6","2016-50-7", "2016-51-1")

# convert to the correct dates
as.Date(paste0(substr(d,1,8), as.integer(substring(d,9))-1), "%Y-%U-%w") + 1
```

which gives:

```
[1] "2016-12-15" "2016-12-16" "2016-12-17" "2016-12-18" "2016-12-19"
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work fine, with one exception, when the number of day in the week equals 1 like "2016-50-1", resulting in NA.

Comment: @KoenV Fixed, I think; added an example with a `1` to demo.

Comment: @Frank. Thank you again. This seems to work perfectly. I will do some additional testing on larger datasets later on, and report back on this forum.

Comment: @Jaap @Frank The correct format string would be `"%G-%V-%u"`. `%G` is the week-based year. As already mentioned this will work only for output as these format specifiers are _Accepted but ignored on input._

Comment: @Frank Your proposal works for most of the dates but not for some near the year end. The dates it is not working for are (not exhaustive):  `"2014-52-6" "2015-53-6" "2015-53-4" "2015-53-1" "2015-53-2" `  This generates NAs.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because for `%u`, `1` is `Monday` and `7` is `Sunday` of the week. The problem is further complicated by the fact that `%U` assumes week begins on Sunday.

For the given input and expected behavior of `format = "%Y-%U-%u"`, the output of line 4 is consistent with the output of previous 3 lines.

That is, if you want to use `format = "%Y-%U-%u"`, you should pre-process your input. In this case, the fourth line would have to be `as.Date("2016-51-7", format = "%Y-%U-%u")` as revealed by

```
format(as.Date("2016-12-18"), "%Y-%U-%u")
# "2016-51-7"
```

Instead, you are currently passing `"2016-50-7"`.

Better way of doing it might be to use the approach suggested in [**Uwe Block's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41726589/7128934) answer. Since you are happy with `"2016-50-4"` being transformed to `"2016-12-15"`, I suspect in your raw data, Monday is counted as `1` too. You could also create a custom function that changes the value of `%U` to count the week number as if week begins on Monday so that the output is as you expected.

```
#Function to change value of %U so that the week begins on Monday
pre_process = function(x, delim = "-"){
    y = unlist(strsplit(x,delim))
    # If the last day of the year is 7 (Sunday for %u),
    # add 1 to the week to make it the week 00 of the next year
    # I think there might be a better solution for this
    if (y[2] == "53" & y[3] == "7"){
        x = paste(as.integer(y[1])+1,"00",y[3],sep = delim)
    } else if (y[3] == "7"){
    # If the day is 7 (Sunday for %u), add 1 to the week 
        x = paste(y[1],as.integer(y[2])+1,y[3],sep = delim)
    }
    return(x)
}
```

And usage would be

```
as.Date(pre_process("2016-50-7"), format = "%Y-%U-%u")
# [1] "2016-12-18"
```

***I'm not quite sure how to handle when the year ends on a Sunday.***

Comment: Thank you. I will test your approach as well. In order to test for years ending on a Sunday, I need to include **2006**. I need time to get these raw data before I can run such a test. Currently, I am doing a first EDA with years 2014-2017.

Comment: @KoenV @Darshan The correct format string would be `"%G-%V-%u"`. `%G` is the week-based year. As already mentioned this will work only for output as these format specifiers are _Accepted but ignored on input._