# Getting the week from the date

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a series of dates and am trying to get the week of the year. This seems to be innacurate.

```
Order_Date = c("2017-06-10","2017-06-11","2017-06-12","2017-06-13",
               "2017-06-14","2017-06-15","2017-06-16")
strftime(as.POSIXlt(Order_Date) ,format="%W")
week(Order_Date)
```

06/10 was a saturday and so there's no way that 06/10 and 06/11 were of the same week.

Any ideas on how to get this?

Comment: `library(lubridate); week(ymd(Order_Date))` gives `23 24 24 24 24 24 24`, so 6/10 and 6/11 are not the same week. Seems right!

Comment: Do week(ymd("2017-06-17")) and it's 25...but it's a saturday and should be 24

Comment: You probably want `format = "%U"`

Comment: @d.b is right. Check the documentation for `strptime`.

Comment: There are different ways of numbering weeks; `?lubridate::week` shows three.

Comment: `format(as.Date("2017-06-17"), "%U")` returns 24.

Comment: `%W` "Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Monday as the first day of week (and typically with the first Monday of the year as day 1 of week 1). The UK convention."

Comment: See %U, %V and %W on the ?strptime page.  If none of those are what you want then you will need to define exactly what it is that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with date-time is not always straightforward. An illustration of your question and the comments from SO members. I added a few days to make the point more clear.

```
library(lubridate)
Order_Date = c("2017-06-10","2017-06-11","2017-06-12","2017-06-13",
               "2017-06-14","2017-06-15","2017-06-16", "2017-06-17",
               "2017-06-18", "2017-06-19")
strftime(as.POSIXlt(Order_Date) ,format="%W") # week starts on Monday
#  [1] "23" "23" "24" "24" "24" "24" "24" "24" "24" "25"

strftime(as.POSIXlt(Order_Date) ,format="%U") # week starts on Sunday
#  [1] "23" "24" "24" "24" "24" "24" "24" "24" "25" "25"

week(Order_Date) # week starts on Sunday
#  [1] 23 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25
```

In a related question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724427/as-date-produces-unexpected-result-in-a-sequence-of-week-based-dates),  I used @UweBlock 's `ISOweek` package to circumvent problems with year-ends after extensive testing. Here is the code:

```
library(ISOweek)
library(stringr)
str_replace(ISOweek(Order_Date), "201.-W", "")  # week starts on Monday (and follows ISO 8601)
#  [1] "23" "23" "24" "24" "24" "24" "24" "24" "24" "25"
```

You can get more information with `?ISOweek`.

Please let me know whether this is what you want.