# Round a POSIX date (POSIXct) with base R functionality

Tags: r, date, datetime, rounding, posixct

I'm currently playing around a lot with dates and times for a package I'm building.

Stumbling across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333838/how-do-you-generate-a-sequence-of-the-last-day-of-the-month-over-two-years-in-r) reminded me again that it's generally not a bad idea to check out if something can be done with basic R features before turning to contrib packages.

Thus, is it possible to round a date of class `POSIXct` with base R functionality?

I checked

```
methods(round)
```

which "only" gave me

```
[1] round.Date      round.timeDate*

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

This is what I'd like to do (Pseudo Code)

```
x <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time())
[1] "2012-07-04 10:33:55 CEST"

round(x, atom="minute")
[1] "2012-07-04 10:34:00 CEST"

round(x, atom="hour")
[1] "2012-07-04 11:00:00 CEST"

round(x, atom="day")
[1] "2012-07-04 CEST"
```

I know this can be done with [timeDate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/index.html), [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) etc., but I'd like to keep package dependencies down. So before going ahead and checking out the source code of the respective packages, I thought I'd ask if someone has already done something like this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`base` has `round.POSIXt` to do this. Not sure why it doesn't come up with `methods`.

```
x <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time())
x
[1] "2012-07-04 10:01:08 BST"
round(x,"mins")
[1] "2012-07-04 10:01:00 BST"
round(x,"hours")
[1] "2012-07-04 10:00:00 BST"
round(x,"days")
[1] "2012-07-04"
```

Comment: great function, but strangely doesnt have week, month, or year rounding; for my situation I'll have to go with @nzcoops answer

Comment: Furthermore, round converts POSIXct to POSIXlt - which sometimes can be a problem.

Comment: ... which can be solved by wrapping the output in `as.POSIXct()`, if desired.

Comment: very helpful and simple solution

Answer (score 20):

On this theme with `lubridate`, also look into the `ceiling_date()` and `floor_date()` functions:

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2009-08-03 12:01:59.23")
ceiling_date(x, "second")
# "2009-08-03 12:02:00 CDT"
ceiling_date(x, "hour")
# "2009-08-03 13:00:00 CDT"
ceiling_date(x, "day")
# "2009-08-04 CDT"
ceiling_date(x, "week")
# "2009-08-09 CDT"
ceiling_date(x, "month")
# "2009-09-01 CDT"
```

Comment: I wish the month rounding was available for POSIXct, because floor_date is painfully slow.

Comment: the question explicitly specify "I know this can be done with timeDate, lubridate etc., but I'd like to keep package dependencies down.".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to call external libraries and want to keep `POSIXct` as I do this is one idea (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876764/r-strptime-year-and-month-with-no-delimiter-returning-na)): use strptime and paste a fake month and day. It should be possible to do it more straight forward, as said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876764/r-strptime-year-and-month-with-no-delimiter-returning-na#comment14493507_6876764)

> "For strptime the input string need not specify the date completely:
>   it is assumed that unspecified seconds, minutes or hours are zero, and
>   an unspecified year, month or day is the current one."

Thus it seems that you *have to* use `strftime` to output a truncated string, paste the missing part and convert again in POSIXct.

This is how an update answer could look:

```
x <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time())
x
[1] "2018-12-27 10:58:51 CET"
round(x,"mins")
[1] "2018-12-27 10:59:00 CET"
round(x,"hours")
[1] "2018-12-27 11:00:00 CET"
round(x,"days")
[1] "2018-12-27 CET"
as.POSIXct(paste0(strftime(x,format="%Y-%m"),"-01"))     #trunc by month
[1] "2018-12-01 CET"
as.POSIXct(paste0(strftime(x,format="%Y"),"-01-01"))     #trunc by year
[1] "2018-01-01 CET"
```