# Round an POSIXct date up to the next day

Tags: r, posixct

I have a question similar to [Round a POSIX date (POSIXct) with base R functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325631/round-a-posix-date-posixct-with-base-r-functionality), but I'm hoping to always round the date up to midnight the next day (00:00:00).

Basically, I want a function equivalent to `ceiling` for POSIX-formatted dates. As with the related question, I'm writing my own package, and I already have several package dependencies so I don't want to add more. Is there a simple way to do this in base R?

Comment: You're going to have issues with timezones and daylight saving time.  Just use `Date` if you don't need the time component.

Comment: I'm web scraping POSIXct-style timestamps, and I'm trying to round them to the next day. I don't know if the `Date` format would work for that...

Comment: So you have POSIXct-style character strings... can't you just strip the time component from the string, convert to `Date` and add 1 to the result?

Comment: I'm actually getting UNIX-style timestamps, which are in nanoseconds. So I was going to strip the nanoseconds and convert to POSIXct, then work with them from there.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide an example of your input (including timezone, if applicable), how you're converting it to POSIXct, and the desired output (including timezone, if applicable).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe

```
trunc(x,"days") + 60*60*24

> x <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time())
> x
[1] "2012-08-09 18:40:08 BST"
> trunc(x,"days")+ 60*60*24
[1] "2012-08-10 BST"
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty method is to convert to a `Date` (which truncates the time), add 1 (which is a day for `Date`) and then convert back to `POSIX` to be at midnight UTC on the next day. As @Joshua Ulrich points out, timezone/daylight savings issues may give results you don't expect:

```
as.POSIXct(as.Date(Sys.time())+1)
[1] "2012-08-10 01:00:00 BST"
```