# R round PosixCT variable in a data table

Tags: r, data.table, posixct

The following code creates a 10 row data table with one variable, timeStamp, in POSIXct format.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(timeStamp = seq( as.POSIXct("2017-07-01 14:51:50"), by=60, len=10))
```

I want to round timeStamp to the nearest minute.

This command puts a list in each row of timeStamp2 rather than modified POSIXct variables.

```
dt[, timestamp2 := round(timeStamp, "mins")]
```

The line of code below does what I want (round up in this example) but doesn't work within the data table.

```
timestamp2 <- round(dt$timeStamp, "mins")
```

I'm using data.table version 1.10.4-3 and MRAN R version 3.4.1.

Comment: `?round.POSIXt` returns a `POSIXlt`. wrap it in `as.POSIXct()` : `dt[, timestamp2 := as.POSIXct(round(timeStamp, "mins"))]`

Comment: @SymbolixAU - that's the answer mate... bung it in the answer box below!

Comment: @thelatemail - I was kinda waiting for someone to find a duplicate for it...

Comment: @SymbolixAU, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325631/round-a-posix-date-posixct-with-base-r-functionality) seems the closest match, but it doesn't clarify the POSIXlt element, so the answer has clear value!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?round.POSIXt`:

> ### Value
>
> An object of class "POSIXlt" or "Date".

Which means the result of `round` on a `POSIX` object is a `POSIXlt` object.

Therefore you need to wrap your `round` function inside `as.POSIXct()` to get it back to `POSIXct`

```
dt[, timestamp2 := as.POSIXct(round(timeStamp, "mins"))]
```